# Python Beginner Collision Detection Problems

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm a beginner at coding and I'm working on a basic platformer game. I've looked at many different resources for the past couple of days and cant quite get a clear picture. At this point I'm pretty lost from switching between one person's method to another person's.
    Right now, I'm looking at this [Pygame tut](http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html). I'm getting the following error:

```
  File ".../PlayerPlat.py", line 87, in <module>

hero = Player(400, 0)

  File ".../PlayerPlat.py", line 10, in __init__

  self.rect = pygame.rect(32, 32, 16, 16)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Code is as follows:

```
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect = pygame.rect(32, 32, 16, 16)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("hero.png")
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx!=0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy!=0:
            self.move_single_axis(0,dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x +=dx
        self.rect.y +=dy

    hero = Player(400, 0)
```

Why is this giving the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with pygame, but [the docs say](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) that `rect` should be capitalized, as in `pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)` - try that.

Answer (score 0):

The method uses a capital **R** not a lowercase r

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16) # capital `R`
```

Comment: @Lal, what explanation more is needed, the method uses a capital `R` not a lowercase `r` I don't see how it could be any clearer

Comment: @Lal, I doubt it was the first incorrect flag. There is only so much one can write about a spelling mistake

Comment: @Lal. it would take a bit more than that ;)

Comment: It was clear enough. No worries! It brought up a multitude of more problems, unfortunately.

Comment: @user3167069, they are the joys of starting off, it will get easier!